# Why does random() work in cstdlib? (Ubuntu 10.10)

Tags: c++, random, overloading, ambiguous

I always thought the random functions in cstdlib were only rand and srand, but the following works (compiled with g++ on Ubuntu 10.10)?

I actually found this out when moving from Windows to Ubuntu, my compilation failed as it was ambiguously overloading (I had declared my own 'random()' function).

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
 srandom(50);
 cout << random();
 return 0;
};
```

---

Also the following compiles correctly on Ubuntu, it appears after checking stdlib.h, that the random() and srandom(), among others, are not declared in the std namespace. Which makes it a complete pain in the arse...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    std::cout << random();
    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because compiler writers are free to add extra things to the language library to make your job easier. Normally, it wouldn't be a problem, because it puts them in a namespace which you won't be adding things to, `std`.

Your problem arises from that little line

```
using namespace std;
```

This pulls *everything* from `std` into your program's namespace, including `std::random`, which the compiler writers helpfully provided. If you instead explicitly declare what you're pulling from `std`, you wouldn't clobber your local `random` with `std::random`:

```
using std::rand;
using std::srand;
```

See also [this question](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/coding-standards.html#faq-27.5) from the c++ FAQ lite.

Comment: I don't think even C++0x defines a std::random(), so although this is sound advice, I don't think it's related to Daniel's issue.

Comment: @Jim never said C++ does define std::random. In fact I think I explained that compiler writers are free to add their own stuff that's not in the C++ standard.

Comment: @Philip: I can't quote chapter and verse of the standard to support this, but I have a strong sense that it's not kosher for compiler vendors to pollute the std:: namespace by adding their own non-standard functions.  Note that Daniel's problem didn't disappear when he removed the "using" declaration!

Comment: @Daniel: I think the POSIX version of random() gets imported into the unnamed namespace (i.e. ::random() ), not the std:: namespace.  You can get around this by enclosing the declaration and definition of your version of random() into your own namespace, then referring to it as (e.g.) daniel::random().

Comment: Thats what I've noticed Jim, I guess I'll have too. See original question for my example of that (for others benefit).

Answer (score 5):

[`random()`](http://linuxmanpages.com/man3/random.3.php) is part of the [Single Unix Specification](http://www.unix.org/apis.html). It’s not part of the C++ Standard. That’s why it’s not on Windows but is found on most Unix/Mac platforms.

Comment: That's `<stdlib.h>`, not `<cstdlib>`. I don't think the SUS has been updated to account for C++ yet.

Comment: On Ubuntu, including `<cstdlib>` pulls in `<stdlib.h>` as a dependency.